# AWS.MechanicalTurk.MustRegister error with MTurk Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I'm having trouble installing and running the Amazon Mechanical Turk "Hello World" for Ruby application that's provided with the mturk gem. I keep getting an error saying: `AWS.MechanicalTurk.MustRegister`.

Here are the steps I took in my failed attempt to install and run the application:

### Setup

I created a project for the application:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/proj/mturk
$ cd ~/proj/mturk
$ rvm --ruby-version use ruby-2.2@mturk --create
$ bundle init
$ echo 'gem "mturk"' >> Gemfile
$ bundle install
$ cp ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@mturk/gems/mturk-1.9.0/samples/helloworld/* .
```

From here, I followed the instructions available at: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkGettingStartedGuide/SetUp.html

I tried twice, once using root credentials and once using IAM credentials, but without success either time. (My preference would be to use IAM credentials if possible for security purposes.)

### Using Root Credentials

To generate and install root credentials in the application:

I navigated my browser to: http://aws.amazon.com/security-credentials
I pressed "Continue to Security Credentials" on the page and downloaded the key file for the root user account. I tried using the credentials for the root user, but without success:

```
$ echo 'AWSAccessKeyId: [redacted]' >> mturk.yml
$ echo 'AWSAccessKey: [redacted]' >> mturk.yml
$ ./MTurkHelloWorld.rb
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@mturk/gems/mturk-1.9.0/lib/amazon/webservices/mturk/mechanical_turk_error_handler.rb:143:in `block in validateResponse': AWS.MechanicalTurk.MustRegister (Amazon::WebServices::Util::ValidationException)
```

### Using IAM

I got the same AWS.MechanicalTurk.MustRegister error message when using IAM as well. To generate and install IAM credentials in the application:

In my web browser, I navigated to the IAM console.
I clicked the 'Policies' option, and selected 'AmazonMechanicalTurkFullAccess.'
I chose 'Attach' from the 'Policy Actions' dropdown, selected a user called "Turk" which I previously created, and pressed the 'Attach Policy' button for full turk access.

Next, I clicked the 'Users' tab, pressed 'Create Access Key' for the "Turk" user, and pressed the 'Download Access Key' button.

I tried using these keys, but without success:

```
$ echo 'AWSAccessKeyId: [redacted]' >> mturk.yml
$ echo 'AWSAccessKey: [redacted]' >> mturk.yml
$ ./MTurkHelloWorld.rb
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@mturk/gems/mturk-1.9.0/lib/amazon/webservices/mturk/mechanical_turk_error_handler.rb:143:in `block in validateResponse': AWS.MechanicalTurk.MustRegister (Amazon::WebServices::Util::ValidationException)
```

This is the same error as before.

Comment: You can't use IAM credentials with MTurk.

Comment: Just a quick update: [AWS announced](http://mechanicalturk.typepad.com/blog/2015/12/introducing-mechanical-turk-api-support-for-iam-credentials.html) that IAM is now supported on MTurk.

Answer (score 3):

"Turk registration in the sandbox is independent of the production system, so you'll need to log on to https://requestersandbox.mturk.com/ and complete the registration process there."

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=123738